# flutter set "ButtonStyle" border color depending on the button state

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, [ButtonStyle] has properties like "backgroundColor" so you have access to the button state so you can set background color depending on the button state. is there any option to set border color like this?

example of "backgroundColor"

```
   backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
              (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                  return pressedColor;
                }
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                  return disableColor;
                }
                return defaultColor;
              },
            ),
```